# Networking between 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and 10.12 (Sierra)

Tags: network, macos, snow-leopard, folders, file-sharing

For work I have to solve an issue involving very old and new systems. Because of legacy software required for the business, I need to sync folders between Mac A (MBP running 10.6.8) and Mac's B and C, both are iMac's running 10.12 Sierra.

I had been using AeroFS before they shut it down and it worked great. Simple folder mirroring. *I want to mirror folders so there are fewer points of failure, and all files are on each system.

Bittorent Sync (Resilio Sync) would work PERFECT except 10.6.8 is too told to run the client.

What is the best way to mirror folders between these systems? I've considered Dropbox, but due to file sizes and slow internet has been ruled out.

Would a NAS be ideal in this situation? How can I best mirror folders between all 3?

EDIT - Mirroring folders is needed as the MacBook Pro is mobile and will need file access away from the internet.

Comment: A NAS would be perfect in this situation.  I personally use the the [Synology Diskstation 212j](http://radnex.us/synology_diskstation_212j) which is more than enough to support at least 5 clients, my dev server, backups, and a Plex Server.  Just use NFS or AFP to mount shares.

Comment: Thanks Allan! Now, with a NAS, I would have to 'mount' the main shared folder everytime to access it correct? Can I 'mirror' a folder on the NAS so it's replicated on all the clients? i.e. files are on the Macbook pro locally when away from the internet.

Comment: Yes.  DSM (os for Synology) allows you to create your own local cloud that will sync for you.  See this [link](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/6.1/cloud_file_syncing).

Comment: I am currently running transmission on Snow Leopard.  Would that work?

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the link! Not having ever used a solution like this, I would like to have the folders be in sync automatically upon any changes. If the folder is on the NAS, would I still have to 'mount' it on the Mac's? If it's mounted, would it then not be a truly local folder?

Comment: @William Thanks for that suggestion, I will check that software out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChronoSync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/overview.html) should be able to do what you want.  While they offer an older version that will run on 10.6.8, I would suggest that, instead, you run the latest version on your 10.12 system and use it to sync the files amongst all your systems.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... I don't think Chronosync will push changes to other folders automatically among 3 computers. I think you have to manually sync them through the software.

Comment: @hwp08 It won't sync in real-time (I.e. as soon as a file is modified), but you can schedule syncs to automatically run as often as you like.  As quickly as once every minute.